# Service should only be accesible between certain times

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I need to create a WCF service that gets some data out of a database. This service should only be accessible at night, for some reason. I have been told this should be possible by some code in web.config, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a way to define in web.config, but it seems like you can use PowerShell to schedule and terminate the service.
[MSDN blog post on scheduling background jobs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/03/19/scheduling-background-jobs-in-windows-powershell-3-0.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in web.config. This is a highly unusual requirement. Certainly not built in.

Just go like this:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 22)
  throw new FaultException("ServiceUnavailable");
```

Answer (score -2):

For a client, you would want to adjust the sendTimeout attribute of a binding element. For a service, you would want to adjust the receiveTimeout attribute of a binding elemnent.

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <netTcpBinding>
      <binding name="longTimeoutBinding"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <security mode="None"/>
      </binding>
    </netTcpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <services>
    <service name="longTimeoutService"
      behaviorConfiguration="longTimeoutBehavior">
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/longtimeout/"
        binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding" />
    </service>
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure whether this answers my question, but I don't think it does. What I want is that my WCF is only accessible between, for instance, 03:00-06:00 AM.

Comment: That's definitely not the solution to the question. Those timeouts are used to define how long a open, close, send and receive may take at most. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx).